# How to plot horizontal lines through markers in plotly?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

Here is some example code I wrote to illustrate my problem. Right now, the plot generates only the points. What I want to do is have horizontal lines that go through each point, spanning a length of 1 to each side. (i.e. for a point at `(2,1)` I want the line to run from `(1,1)` to `(3,1)`) How can I do this in `plotly`? I've looked [here](https://plot.ly/r/shapes/#lines) but can't seem to figure out how to get this to work when the y-axis is not numerical.

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mtcars$mpg, y = rownames(mtcars), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
p
```

**EDIT**[image: Here] is the output from the code provided in the accepted answer (except showing all car names). I was wondering if there is a way to draw a horizontal line between each y-axis label, so that for example, between "Volvo 142E" and "Maserati Bora", a line separates them, and goes for the length of the plot. Right now, each horizontal line of the plot has a point on it. I want to separate each of those lines with another line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work we had to replot the original scatter plot with an using the row index to prevent plotly from reordering cars. Then I added back to the axis labels.

```
library(plotly)
##I added the text argument(hover over text) so that I could make sure
##that the yaxis labels matched the points. feel free to delete.
p <- plot_ly(x = mtcars$mpg, y = seq_along(rownames(mtcars)), text=rownames(mtcars),
             type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

##This sets some attributes for the yaxis. Note: in your origianl plot every other
##car name was shown on the y-axis so that is what I recreated but you could remove
##the "seq(1,32, by=2)" to show all car names.
ax <- list(
  title = "",
  ticktext = rownames(mtcars)[seq(1,32, by=2)],
  tickvals = seq(1,32, by=2)
)

##This is taken from the plotly help page. y0 and y1 now are set to equal the row
##number and x0 and x1 are +/-1 from the car's mpg    
line <- list(
  type = "line",
  line = list(color = "pink"),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y"
)

lines <- list()
for (i in seq_along(rownames(mtcars))) {
  line[["x0"]] <- mtcars$mpg[i] - 1
  line[["x1"]] <- mtcars$mpg[i] + 1
  line[c("y0", "y1")] <- i
  lines <- c(lines, list(line))
}

p <- layout(p, title = 'Highlighting with Lines', shapes = lines, yaxis=ax)
p
```

### Update based on OP's request.

To underline text in plotly use HTML tags. But `<u> </u>` does not work so we have to use `<span> </span>`...

```
ax2 <- list(
  title = "", ticktext = paste0('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">', 
                                rownames(mtcars)[1:32 %% 2 ==0],"</span>"),
  tickvals = seq(1,32, by=2), style=list(textDecoration="underline"))
```

Comment: Awesome explanation!

Comment: in this example, is there a way to separate each y-axis label with a horizontal line? I can ask this in a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you could post an example output I will see what I can do.

Comment: See my edit, and let me know if it does not make sense

Comment: There is likely a way to do it by adding some custom JS to the yaxis layout call. But I'm not sure, and that is outside my wheel house

Comment: See my edit, you can replace the `ax` with new `ax2` to get underlined labels.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to the actual graph as well? I realize my question was a bit misleading with my wording. But ideally I'd like that exact line across the entire plot.